# In Spotfire, how to trellis a SummaryTable using IronPython script

Tags: spotfire

I am trying to "trellis" a summary table using a script. The TrellisVisualization is not available for the SummaryTable class. Using the GUI, I can trellis a summary table by assigning a specific column to the Categorization property under Columns Properties. However, while using the IronPython script, I don't see any property named Categorization for the SummaryTable object. So, I tried assigning the column to the CategoryAxis as follows:

```
    mySummaryTable.CategoryAxis = "<[myColumn]>"
```

But this throws an error:

```
    AttributeError: 'SummaryTable' object has no attribute 'CategoryAxis'
```

I also tried using Axis or CategoricalAxisBase etc. as properties, but these options did not work out. If anyone has more ideas on this, please let me know. Thanks.
RD

Answer (score 2):

The key issue here is that the CategoryAxis property underneath the Summary Table class is a GET of this visual's object of the GroupByAxis class. You can see this by using the print command and getting information about the object:

```
print mySummaryTable.CategoryAxis
```

results in my Spotfire example:
`<Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals.GroupByAxis object at 0x000000000000002C [Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals.GroupByAxis]>`

You were actually quite close though. In order to set the CategoryAxis you need to set the Expression property of the CategoryAxis like so:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import SummaryTable

mySummaryTable = myVisual.As[SummaryTable]()
mySummaryTable.CategoryAxis.Expression = "<[COLUMN]>"
```

If you need to pass an actual column name into that rather than hardcoded, I would concatenate the expression syntax and set the Expression equal to that variable:

```
myColumnExp = "<[" + myColumnName + "]>"
mySummaryTable.CategoryAxis.Expression = myColumnExp
```

Please let me know if you need any clarity regarding this. My Spotfire version for this answer is v6.5.2.26 and my API information from https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/spotfire/6.5.0/api/Index.aspx